# How can I slice a string according to a list of sorted integers?

Tags: python

let's say I have a `string`

`s = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP'`

and a `list` of sorted `integers`

`lst = [1, 4, 5, 9]`

How do I write a function to take the `integers` and `slice` the `string` accordingly?

Required output:

```
1)'A'[:1]

2) 'BCD' [1:4]

3) 'E' [4:5]

4) 'FGHI' [5:9]

5) 'JKLMNOP' [9:]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can construct explicit [`slice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) objects with your indexes and then index the string using those slices.

From then it boils down to the usual "How do I get paired objects from a sequence" that Python doesn't really have a builtin solution for.

A slightly evil, compact solution, making use of the fact that [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) can iterate over multiple sequences in lock-step:

```
s = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP'
idx = [1, 4, 5, 9]
parts = [s[slc] for slc in map(slice, [0] + idx, idx + [None])]
```

Don't do this if you have many indexes, since it constructs two intermediate lists on the fly for the indexes.

Obviously, if one can massage `idx` beforehand, it's also possible to

```
from itertools import imap
s = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP'
idx = [0, 1, 4, 5, 9, None]
parts = [s[slc] for slc in imap(slice, idx[:-1], idx[1:])]
```

Comment: Alternatively, `[s[a:b] for a, b in zip([0] + idx, idx + [None])]`

Comment: @tobias_k ... and of course using `itertools.imap()` (`itertools.izip()`) to once more avoid the intermediate lists in Python2.

Answer (score 2):

My solution isn't the most elegant, but it is very simple and it scales well.

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) for list slicing syntax, all list slices have the form `list[start:end]`. Omitting `start` gives it the value 0, and omitting `end` gives it the value `len(list)`.

So solving your problem becomes really easy if you add 0 and `len(list)` to your indexes, effectively removing the trickiest part of your specification, which is the first and last indices:

```
numbers = [1, 4, 5, 9]
string = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP'

numbers.append(len(string))
numbers.insert(0,0)

result = [string[numbers[i]:numbers[i+1]] for i in range(len(numbers)-1)]
```

Output:

```
>>> print(result)
['A', 'BCD', 'E', 'FGHI', 'JKLMNOP']
```